# Generating items via v-for and v-if condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have code something like this in A.vue file

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <item :item="item" />
</div>
```

In Item.vue file:

```
<div class="item">
    <div v-if="item.xyz">
        long and complex html here
    </div>
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</div>
```

Now consider that items has some 100 items and only one item.xyz is true. As v-if is not mounting any html into DOM until the condition is true but its definitely keeping the data in memory of vue object.

Is there any way to consider v-if only for one item and not for others?

Comment: Filtering will not fix the issue, as I need to generate item.name for all items, just for one item where item.xyz is true I need extra component

Comment: When you say *'keeping the data in memory of vue object'*, what exactly do you mean? Are you referring to the empty VDOM node that gets created or the dependency tracking on `xyz`? Or something else? Either way I'm not sure it's actually worth worrying about but I would like to be clear about exactly what you're trying to achieve before attempting an answer.

Comment: Technically, in the above example for all items inside v-if, vue has generated some code to render the div. As the condition is not true, so it will not be mounted to DOM of the document. So my concern is in the above example how I can make sure that vue has generated the code only once for one item?

Comment: If the item.xyz is set to true for some item. vue is generating and mounting the div into the DOM from 'somewhere'. That somewhere is the memory which is holding the code for 100 div even for only 1 div I need to generate the html.

Comment: It won't create the DOM nodes for the other 99 divs. It might be creating extra empty VDOM nodes (manifesting as comments in the DOM) but that generally isn't worth worrying about. The only reliable way to avoid that is to write the `render` function yourself.

Comment: just make A.vue functional component. take a look [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components)